# Flutter: Dynamically change widgets size in appBar

Tags: flutter

I am trying to do the following:
I want to change sizes of appBar title and widgets in actions[...] dynamically when the size of appBar itself is being changed.
I want to set the width of the title to be 75% and width of a widget(a raised button) in actions to be 30% of the width of appBar itself and when the size of appBar is changed (For example when I make it bigger or smaller when pulling the app window with mouse), I want the sizes(width in this case) of title and the mentioned widget(the raised button) to change accordingly.

I tried to use:

1. child: ButtonTheme(
   minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
   ),
2. minWidth: AppBar().preferredSize.width
3. Flexible widget
4. Expanded widget
5. FractionallySizedBox.  ...e.t.c

but i couldn't achieve the above mentioned behavior.

Take into consideration the simplest appBar example:

```
/// Flutter code sample for AppBar
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const AlbertsApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class AlbertsApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const AlbertsApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatelessWidget(),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateless widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Alberts trial AppBar'),
        actions : <Widget> [
          RaisedButton (
            child: Text('Hi'),
            color: Colors.red,
            onPressed: () {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  const SnackBar(content: Text('This is a TonysChoocolonely')));
            },
          ),
          RaisedButton (
            child: Text('Bye'),
            color: Colors.green,
            onPressed: () {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  const SnackBar(content: Text('This is a KitKat')));
            },
          ),
          RaisedButton (
            child: Text('Third'),
            color: Colors.yellow,
            onPressed: () {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  const SnackBar(content: Text('This is a PeanutButter')));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text(
          'This Is The Home Page Itself',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here at any moment, when the appBar size is being changed, I want the title and raised buttons' sizes to change accordingly.
For example, at any moment, when appBar width becomes 'x', i want the title width to become 'x * 70 / 100', and width of every raised button to become 'x * 30 / 100'.

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: @Diwyansh 
Thanks for responding. I can't add the code itself, but you can take into consideration the simplest appBar example. I have already updated the question with one.

Comment: can you clarify you need title(75%)+action(30%+30%+30%) there are thee buttons in your sample code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and how I did was just getting rid of the `actions` and use the `Row()` widget in the `body:`. Then divide the widget with `Container`

```
  body: const Row(
    children: [
        Container(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.15) //Container 1
        Container(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.70) //Container 2
        Container(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.15) //Container 3
    ]
  ),
```

Then the size will be set as you wish the divide them into. You can add `Text()` to `Container2` and all your buttons to `Container1`. Or, you can set different size and use like `mainAxis` to the `Row()` widget.

But just make sure you kinda have three containers or add sizedbox to even out with the first container in order to make the 2nd container in the centre centre!